# Recording M4A file on iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to record voice with m4a extension. I used the below code:

```
            try! self.audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord,
                withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DefaultToSpeaker)

            try! self.audioSession.setActive(true)


            //get documnets directory
            let documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
            let fullPath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("voiceRecord.m4a")
            let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(fullPath)

            //create AnyObject of settings
            let settings: [String : AnyObject] = [
                AVFormatIDKey:Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                AVSampleRateKey:44100.0,
                AVNumberOfChannelsKey:1,
                AVEncoderBitRateKey:12800,
                AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey:16,
                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey:AVAudioQuality.Low.rawValue
            ]

            //record
            try! self.audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: url, settings: settings)
            self.audioRecorder.record()
            print("kayıt başladı")
```

This code is creating a .m4a file which size is 28 byte. If record length is 30 seconds or 5 seconds it doesn't matter the file size is 28 byte. As you can imagine file is corrupted.

Where is the problem? Why this is not working properly?

Comment: You should call `prepareToRecord()`. Set the delegate and check if there is an issue (`audioRecorderEncodeErrorDidOccur(_ recorder:error:)`).

Comment: @Larme I implemented it but it returns nothing you can check: http://prntscr.com/e6wlcj

Comment: are you testing in real device?

Comment: Yes i am testing in real device

Comment: and what about  `requestRecordPermission`

Comment: did you try that?

Comment: Of course, i have the permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. Changed my settings to this:

```
            let settings = [
                AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
                AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.High.rawValue
            ]
```

And problem disappeared.